# RegEx: Match LaTeX-like function with optional parameters

Tags: php, regex

I want to match something like a LaTeX function with optional parameters in PHP.

Following examples should match the pattern:

```
example{arg0}
example{arg0}{opt1}
example{arg0}{opt1}{opt2}
example{arg0}{opt1}{opt2}{opt3}
```

As you can see first parameter is required but following parameters (opt1-3) are optional.

I got this one:

```
/example\{(.*)\}(\{(.*)\})?(\{(.*)\})?(\{(.*)\})?/U
```

But it's only matching the first parameters (see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/e4TTjm/1)).

What RegEx will recognize each line as match and parameters opt1-3 as groups?

Comment: As you use the U-flag, all your optional groups are lazy, thus don't match if they don't need to. You might make them lazy again by using `(..)??` or don't use U. You could also consider using a negated character class instead of lazy `.*`, like `[^}\n\r]*`

Comment: Not using modifier `U` ist not working (tried that before). But doubling all the question marks did the trick! Thank you very much :) If you put it as answer I'll choose and upvote.

Comment: I were too happy too soon. Looks like it's working in PCRE but not with PHP :/

Comment: *Looks like it's working in PCRE but not with PHP* - You are definitely not using the regex properly. Please share the code you are using.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're right, I did some mistake changing two lines of code at same time -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `/U` greediness switching modifier and replace all `.*` with `[^{}]*`:

```
'~example(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKbhYC/1)

**Details**:

- `example` - a string `example`
- `(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?` - an optional group matching a `{`, then capturing zero or more characters other than `{` and `}`, then matching `}`
- `(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?` - ibid. (3 more repetitions of the subpattern above)

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/yavZWu):

```
$re = '~example(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?(?:\{([^{}]*)\})?~';
$str = 'example{arg0}
example{arg0}{opt1}
example{arg0}{opt1}{opt2}
example{arg0}{opt1}{opt2}{opt3}';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```